# Geo spatial queries with Doctrine MongoDB ODM

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm

I have a 2d index on a coordinates property of my document. Using the mongo shell, I can query the collection like this;

```
db.adverts.find({coordinates:{$near:[20,40]}})
```

And that returns the following results, as expected;

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fddac51352de93903000000"), "title" : "dummy #3", "coordinates" : { "longitude" : 22, "latitude" : 31 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fddac48352de95105000000"), "title" : "dummy #3", "coordinates" : { "longitude" : 20, "latitude" : 30 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fddaca4352de93703000000"), "title" : "dummy #3", "coordinates" : { "longitude" : 31, "latitude" : 22 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fdda6a2352de90a03000000"), "title" : "dummy title", "created" : ISODate("2012-06-17T09:42:58Z"), "coordinates" : { "longitude" : 54.1234, "latitude" : -1.234 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fdda6d8352de9c004000000"), "title" : "dummy title #2", "created" : ISODate("2012-06-17T09:43:52Z"), "coordinates" : { "longitude" : 54.34, "latitude" : -1.124 } }
```

However, using Doctrine as per the documentation to query the exact same collection, I get no results e.g.

```
$adverts = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Advert')
                      ->field('coordinates')->near(20, 40)
                      ->getQuery()
                      ->execute();
$adverts->count(); // => 0
```

My advert yaml looks like this;

```
Advert:
    type: document
    collection: adverts
    fields:
        id:
            id: true
        title:
            type: string
        content:
            type: string
        created:
            type: date
        updated:
            type: date
        status:
            type: int
        distance:
            type: int

    indexes:
        coordinates:
            keys:
                coordinates: 2d

    referenceOne:
        owner:
            targetDocument: User

    embedOne:
        coordinates:
            targetDocument: Coordinates
```

And the Coordinates document is like this;

```
Coordinates:
    type: embeddedDocument
    fields:
        longitude:
            type: float
        latitude:
            type: float
```

Any ideas why using Doctrine's ODM would return zero results on the same query?

UPDATE #1
It looks that there is a problem with Doctrine\MongoDB\Query\Builder::near() L363. The method parameter ignores the second value ($y). So only the first value is being passed to be executed.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but shouldn't coordinates be defined as a field in Advert.yaml since it is after all -a field-.  Or is that the purpose of EmbedOne.

Comment: What does getQuery() returns? Also, be aware that MongoDB wants the order in the coordinates field to be: latitude, longitude. It does *not* care about what the fields are called.

Comment: Derick - getQuery() returns an instance of Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Query\Query. Geoist - the embedOne specifies the coordinates property

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an implementation issue with the `near()` method (see https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/pull/53). To fix my original query, I would need to do the following;

```
$adverts = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Advert')
              ->field('coordinates.latitude')->near(20)
              ->field('coordinates.longitude')->near(40);

$adverts->getQuery()->count(); // => 5
```

This contradicts the current documentation that implies both x, y coordinates can be passed to  Doctrine\MongoDB\Query\Builder::near().

EDIT

To make life easier, I've created a custom repository class to provide a more intuitive solution for this inconsistency;

```
public function near($longitude, $latitude)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
                  ->field('coordinates.longitude')->near((float) $longitude)
                  ->field('coordinates.latitude')->near((float) $latitude)
                  ->getQuery();

    return $query;
}
```